# Why can't I create extension methods for static classes?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, static-classes

When I try to create an extension method for the File class, I get an error telling me that I cannot do this because the class is static. However, I don't see why this stops the creation of an extension method, what implication is there?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extension methods are called on an instance of an object.

```
myObj.ExtensionMethod();
```

If you have a static class, you can't have an instance of it.  Therefore, there's nothing to call the extension method on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is a shame but not a big loss.

Answer (score 5):

Because an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) by design must take an instance of the class it is extending as its first parameter. And obviously you can't pass an instance of File because it is a static class and cannot have instances.

Answer (score 5):

Stated in reverse, if you look at the [definition of any extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), the first parameter is always the instance of the object upon which it is called evidenced by the `this` keyword. Logically this behaviour cannot work on a static class because there is no instance present.

Sample of an extension method - **see first param this**

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int WordCount(this String str)
    {
        return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why can’t I create extension methods for static classes?

Because the C# dev team didn't implement that feature (yet). [F# has chosen to implement it](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2008/09/10/object-oriented-f-extension-everything.aspx) though.

Same thing for extension properties. F# has them and [Boo has had them since (at least) 2006](http://groups.google.com/group/boolang/msg/8fafdbf27688f79b).